# Am I learning the right version of Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to start making apps for android in Eclipse, and I have bought a book which will teach me about Java 2 (J2SE 5.0) from Ivor Horton. Will this knowledge of Java be good for Android apps, or is it completely outdated?

Comment: Well it should teaches you the basics of Java and that gives you a good start to Android. If you have done some Java programming, you can start to dive into the Android guides/tutorials on the official Android site and/or on dozens of developer blogs

Comment: okay, so basically when I learn everything from this book, I'll be able to understand android app codes from tutorials?

Comment: @user3539825 Not necessarily. You might understand the *basics*, but the *specific* stuff from the Android API you'll need to find elsewhere, especially if Java 6/7 features are being used.

Answer (score 2):

No version of Java is truly 'outdated' in the sense I think you mean. There has since been a great deal of extra functionality added to the language, but not removed.

So you may not learn about some things that are now possible with the language, but nothing you learn is likely to have gone out of date except some smalls exception with regards to Java applets (which are not really relevant in Android development anyway).

Android is now capable of handling Java 7 code, so it probably wouldn't be worth learning the in-and-outs of Java 8 if your learning it specifically for Android development.

Comment: okay, so basically when I learn everything from this book, I'll be able to understand android app codes from tutorials?

Comment: I am not familiar with 'Ivor Horton' or his works, but if the book is good, then yes.

Comment: well this book is from 2006, so I was just afraid I wouldn't be able to understand android codes. I know they'll be a bit different, but I need to understand them at least

Comment: Android programming uses tools for Java 6 and Java 7. If you are new to programming, I strongly recommend the [Head First Java, Second Edition](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/) book from O’Reilly over the Horton book, though it too is aimed at Java 5.